# Two divs in html fullscreen percentage (not working)

Tags: html, css, percentage

I have my code and I want the two divs to fit together but its not working. The .nav tag is 10% wide and the content is 90% wide. so they should fit together. Thanks for the help.

Here is my HTML and css:

```css
.hf {
 text-align: center;
 background-color: blue;
 color: white;
 clear: both;
 padding: 5px;
}
.nav {
 width: 10%;
 padding: 5px;
 border-style: solid;
 background-color: orange;
 line-height: 200%;
 float: left;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}
.content {
 width: 90%;
 float: left;
 background-color: yellow;
 padding: 0px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Basic Layout</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="hf">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="nav">
  <a href="#">Home</a><br>
  <a href="#">Home</a><br>
  <a href="#">Home</a><br>
  <a href="#">Home</a><br>
  <a href="#">Home</a><br>
  <a href="#">Home</a><br>
  <a href="#">Home</a><br>
  <a href="#">Home</a><br>
  <a href="#">Home</a><br>
 </div>
 <div class="content">
  <h3>Content</h3>
  <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
 </div>
</body>
```

and here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the border width. You gave one element 10% and the 90%, then add 2px for the nav border and you went over the 100%. A better way to achieve this is to use `ul` for menus, as it is usual to do, with good reason. Apply the background and borders to that `ul` and leave your nav container as a container that only contains the width

Here is a better solution to your code:

HTML:

```
<div class="hf">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
</div>
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <h3>Content</h3>
    <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over
        the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.hf {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    clear: both;
    padding: 5px;
    width:100%;
}
.nav {
    width: 10%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.nav ul{
    background-color: orange;
    border:2px solid #333;
    margin-top:0;
}
.nav ul li{
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:5px 0;
}
.content {
    width: 90%;
    float: left;
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

See it working here in this [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/bEZVRX)

You are on the right track, the key to a good responsive web design is to always satisfy that 100% rule. DO NOT reduce the container's with for the sake of fitting a border. You will not get it right. For example, reducing the nav to 9% will overcompensate for the 4px you went over (2px of border width on each side of the nav).

The proper way is to structure your page by creating your containers, and then place the elements you want inside this containers and style those.

Comment: Thanks so much. That makes so much sense.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css code:

```
*{
  box-sizing:border-box}
```

It will work

Answer (score 0):

it just because of border on .nav class , border also have some width , you have to decrease the nav width ,

```css
.hf {
 text-align: center;
 background-color: blue;
 color: white;
 clear: both;
 padding: 5px;
}
.nav {
 width: 9%;
 padding: 5px;
 border-style: solid;
 background-color: orange;
 line-height: 200%;
 float: left;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}
.content {
 width: 90%;
 float: left;
 background-color: yellow;
 padding: 0px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Basic Layout</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="hf">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="nav">
  <a href="#">Home</a><br>
  <a href="#">Home</a><br>
  <a href="#">Home</a><br>
  <a href="#">Home</a><br>
  <a href="#">Home</a><br>
  <a href="#">Home</a><br>
  <a href="#">Home</a><br>
  <a href="#">Home</a><br>
  <a href="#">Home</a><br>
 </div>
 <div class="content">
  <h3>Content</h3>
  <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
 </div>
</body>
```

ps: two way to do this, either don't give border or just decease the width according to border suppose if your border is 5px you have to decrease the width of nav 5px ;

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem a few days ago.Even though the distribution of content was 10:90 ratio, the second div would go down.

> Why is this happening?

It's happening because of the border that you have given to the first div.

> How to fix it?

One solution is you allow the border to remain and decrease the second div to 89% or so.

**Updated CSS**

```
 .hf {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    clear: both;
    padding: 5px;
}
.nav {
    width: 10%;

    border:1px solid black;
    background-color: orange;
    line-height: 200%;
    float: left;

    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.content {
    width: 89%;
    float: left;
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 0px;

    margin: 0px;
}
```

Here's a working [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/w8e5tjy5/)

Answer (score 0):

It is because it will count like:  (10% + border size + 90%). So,  it become more than 100%.

To solve it you can use **[calc](https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/)**.

like: `width: calc(10% - 6px);` Here border size is. 3px so, (3px left + 3px right) will be minus from 10%(width).

Updated code.

```css
.hf {
 text-align: center;
 background-color: blue;
 color: white;
 clear: both;
 padding: 5px;
}
.nav {
 width: 10%;
 padding: 5px;
 border-style: solid;
 background-color: orange;
 line-height: 200%;
 float: left;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
  width: calc(10% - 6px); // Here.
}
.content {
 width: 90%;
 float: left;
 background-color: yellow;
 padding: 0px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Basic Layout</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="hf">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="nav">
  <a href="#">Home</a><br>
  <a href="#">Home</a><br>
  <a href="#">Home</a><br>
  <a href="#">Home</a><br>
  <a href="#">Home</a><br>
  <a href="#">Home</a><br>
  <a href="#">Home</a><br>
  <a href="#">Home</a><br>
  <a href="#">Home</a><br>
 </div><!--
  --><div class="content">
  <h3>Content</h3>
  <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
 </div>
</body>
```